# Can high voltage power lines provide a super highway for drones?

Tags: quadcopter, sensors, power, electronics, machine-learning

Is there a way to convert the EM field that surrounds high voltage power lines for direct usable electricity for air or ground drones for continuous flight or travel?

Added: Yes could the EM field be used for a guide as well?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280558/can-high-voltage-power-lines-provide-a-super-highway-for-drones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, a drone can land on a powerline. That's a standard task like the "peg in hole problem" for robotarms. The aim is to maneuver a UAV near to a highvoltage line and eating all the energy. The earliest paper was written in 2009 and has a nice plotchart of the Electro-Magnetic Field on page 8 [Powerline perching with a fixed-wing UAV](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.719.650&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for directing the UAV in 2D space.

A little bit more tricky is the question of how to program such a device, that it can lands autonomously. A behaviortree which is implemented as a Python thread would be a good starting point. Some routines for goalfinding, fallback handling and number of trials has to be implemented.

In pseudocode the landing procedure is:

```
class BehaviortreePerching():
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def BTstart(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.taskmain)
    t.start()
  def taskmain(self):
    if self.landing()==success: self.harvesting()
    else self.retry()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think yes it can but how? My options are here:

1. **Static system** for conventional systems

   - It should stand or hang to line/pole/special place like birds. Please watch video for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvRTALJp8DM
2. **Dynamic system**

   - Harmless/secure distance present day wireless charging methods: use low energy harvesting drone or an alternative design like blimp-drone and use wireless charging along the line.